# TencentQQ - URL getting split when mixing mandarin and english URLs (decodeURIComponent)

Tags: javascript, web, encoding, utf-8

We are implementing share functionality with TencentQQ using their static share URL. We have an encoded URL: "http://www.testurl.com/product/this-is-a-product-%E7%9F%AD%E8%A3%A4/id-000000"

When this link is shared via TencentQQ using this link: 
http://share.v.t.qq.com/index.php?c=share&a=index&url=http://www.testurl.com/product/this-is-a-product-%E7%9F%AD%E8%A3%A4/id-000000&title=This%20is%20a%20test&appkey=000000000

You will see on your feed that the URL is being split at the start of the Mandarin characters. [image: URL Being Split]

I imagine that they are using decodeURIComponent when processing the URL, which I notice has the same effect when executed in Chrome's dev tools console:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

I guess the question here is -- am I doing something wrong in encoding this URL? Is there a reason that the URL is being split at the start of the Mandarin characters?

Comment: I don't think it's the `decodeURIComponent` that's the problem here, it's more likely the regular expression that makes it display as a link. It returns what it should. In the Chrome Console I can understand why, in the code you are having trouble with, I don't know. Have you tried to contact support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL isn't encoded, it looks like it was encoded because it uses non-ASCII/non-Latin characters, any URL that has another URL inside as a parameter needs to be encoded, long story short, here is the solution:

```
function urlShare(url,title,appkey){
    return 'http://share.v.t.qq.com/index.php?c=share&a=index&url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(title)+'&appkey='+appkey
}
```

Just call this function with the URL, Title and appkey (don't know if the appkey need to be encoded):

```
urlShare('http://www.testurl.com/product/this-is-a-product-%E7%9F%AD%E8%A3%A4','A Title','id-000000')
```

It will return a safe URL that actually works.